# Multiple column to single column with column header?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot-table, unpivot

I have table like following. 
  Staging table:

```
+---------+------+--------+------+
|   Id    | I1   | I2     | I3   | 
+---------+------+--------+------+
|    1    | x1   | 1      |  2   |
|    2    | C    | A      |  B   |
|    3    | x7   | x8     |  X9  |
+---------+------+--------+------+
```

I'm using following query to pivot this table:

```
select    ID
,value
from dbo.Staging
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (I1, I2,I3 )     
) un
```

I want "Column header name" from the staging table also like following. How can I do this?

```
+-------+-------+-------------------------+
| value | ID    |  Column header name     |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+
|  x1   |  1    |       I1                |
|  1    |  1    |       I2                |
|  2    |  1    |       I3                |
|  C    |  2    |       I1                |
|  A    |  2    |       I2                |
|  B    |  2    |       I3                | 
|  x7   |  3    |       I1                |
|  x8   |  3    |       I2                | 
|  x9   |  3    |       I3                |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: With modified table values I'm getting wrong result.I have modified the source table values in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a fixed number of columns which you know beforehand (3 in this case), and that all values are non-null, you could hard-code the column names into your output, like so:

```
;with cte as
 (select 
  ID,
  value,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by value) rn
  from dbo.Staging
  unpivot
  (
   value
   for col in (I1, I2,I3 )     
  ) un
 )

 select 
 id, 
 value, 
 case when rn = 1 then 'I1' when rn = 2 then 'I2' else 'I3' end as 'Column header name'
 from cte
```

EDIT: Since the values might not be in order always, we can use `ID` with `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause. This is effectively a dummy value passed for sorting, so that it will always return the data as is without actually sorting.

Comment: I have modified my question, could you pl look it now?

Comment: With my modified source table values, its not working for me.

Comment: Thanks. I want to insert this into another table.I have written it like this: Insert into dbo.A(ID,DetailID,Value) select ( your query) I'm getting two error: Incorrect syntax near ';' and Incorrect syntax near ')'. How can I correct this?

Comment: The insert part should be between the `with` and `select` parts. Please lookup inserting with CTE to get a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

I never remember the UNPIVOT syntax and limitation so I use CROSS APPLY VALUES

```
SELECT Id
      ,Value
      ,ColumnName
FROM dbo.Staging
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES (I1, 'I1')
               ,(I2, 'I2')
               ,(I3, 'I3')
     ) AS CA1(Value, ColumnName)
```

Comment: Getting syntax error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.I'm using SQL 2005. Will it work in SQL 2005?

Comment: @bapi, No SQL2008 is required. Why tag your question SQL2008 if you are on 2005?

Comment: My compatability level SQL server 2005(90). I'm not allowed to change this.

Comment: @adrianm You can still use `CROSS APPLY` with SQL Server 2005, just use `SELECT...UNION ALL` instead of `VALUES`